# Address Dulicate removal in SQL?

Tags: sql

HI I have a table which holds about 24,000 rows of patients. We have to make a mailing to the patients and only want one to go to the same home.

We already have the last name in its own column.

```
COL A                    COL E 

SMITH                100 Main St.
SMITH                100 Main Street
```

I need to code condition:

If the last name is the same and the street number is the same
and the first word is the same (would have to expand to 2 name and even 3 named streets)

so here, I have SMITH, 100 and MAIN, then I want to output only the first row.

Can this be coded in a plain SQL or needs a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming U.S. addresses, but the same principle would apply anywhere.

To purge duplicates, you need to standardize the address fields so they are formatted consistently, and ***only after standardization*** you can query for duplicates within your tables.  You're going to need some tool outside of sql server to do this correctly.

There are several tools on the market.  USPS actually has an address standardization format, and you want a tool that adheres to the post office requirements because it includes a database (used by all providers, regardless of implementation) that gives their tools intelligence on correct address number ranges, directional (N, S, W, E), prefix/suffix (Street, Avenue, etc) and so forth.

Any provider wishing to advertise as "USPS certified" is given a set of test data to run through their tool, producing a text file to send back to USPS.  That file's contents has to match a response file (which is created by USPS, and not shared with the public) 100% to meet their tough standard.

This is the USPS reference: http://pe.usps.gov/cpim/ftp/pubs/Pub28/pub28.pdf It's not gonna help you directly, but it'll help you understand.

Manual parsing, without the USPS database underneath, fails miserably.

Comment: I agree, name and address parsing and matching software will get you much more accuracy.  From your example the address data is not standardized at point of entry and depending on the specific data you might improve as dramatically as 30% matching to 95%.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you started. The ELSE condition is there in case there is only a number and one word, otherwise the extra CHARINDEX will cause errors. Just replace @blah with col_E in the real query.

```
DECLARE @blah VARCHAR(100)

-- SET @blah = '100 main'
SET @blah = '100 main st'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@blah, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @blah)) AS col_E_Part1, 
    SUBSTRING(@blah, CHARINDEX(' ', @blah) + 1, 
                CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', @blah, CHARINDEX(' ', @blah) + 1) - (CHARINDEX(' ', @blah) + 1) > 0 
                    THEN CHARINDEX(' ', @blah, CHARINDEX(' ', @blah) + 1) - (CHARINDEX(' ', @blah) + 1)
                    ELSE LEN(@blah) END) AS col_E_blah_Part2
```